# Multi-thread access to static variable

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I am studying multi-threading in .net and I stuck on that example:

```
    class Program
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> Channels;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Channels = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();


            Thread adding = new Thread(AddItem);
            Thread reading = new Thread(CountItems);

            reading.Start();
            adding.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void AddItem()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                i++;
                Channels.TryAdd(i.ToString(), i);
                Console.WriteLine(i + ": Item Added");

                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }

        public static void CountItems()
        {
           while (true)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(Channels.Count);
              Thread.Sleep(3000);
           }
        }    
    }
```

Output is:

```
1: Item Added
1
2: Item Added
2
3: Item Added
4: Item Added
4
```

Question is, why those two threads works without Lock? Shouldn't be that reading thread shouldn't see changes?

[Source 1](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/volatility.shtml)

[Source 2](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword)

Comment: So you basically want to see how multithreaded access to dictionary can go wrong? Or you want to see that specifically in your example (with `Count`)?

Comment: _"why those two threads works without Lock?"_ -- why shouldn't they? _"Shouldn't be that reading thread shouldn't see changes?"_ -- let's start with you explaining why you think that's the case. It's not the case, but it's impossible to provide an answer that would be useful to you without knowing how you got so far off base in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

First up, there is a lock, but it is inside the ConcurrentDictionary

Next, check what a lock means. It means that no 2 threads can enter the lock, in this case access the dictionary, at the exact sime instant in time.

It does not mean that each thread cannot see what the other thread can see. Both threads see the exact same object reference, so both access the same data, just not at exactly the same time. The lock is only in place inside the calls to Count or TryAdd.

To see why locking is important, check this simplest possible example:

```
i = i + 1;
```

This looks like 1 statement, but it will be compiled to many machine code instructions, something like this:

1. load the value of i out of memory
2. add 1 to it
3. store the new value mack into memory

When you have multiple threads, it is these machine intsructions that are interleaved together, not the C#. Why is this important? Well, if you had 2 threads executing the above statement at the same time then this might happen:

imagine i = 42

1. thread 1 loads value of i from mem (42)
2. thread 2 loads value of i from mem (still 42)
3. thread 1 adds 1 and stores the result in memory (now 43)
4. thread 2 does the same (it stores 43 too)

So, there were 2 attempts to increment i, but the result was it was only incremented one time.

Now imagine what might be going on inside a dictionary class - probably alot more that just incrementing a counter - there is no way of telling what might happen if 2 threads do something at the same time.

Now if you do this:

```
lock (someObject) 
{
    i = i + 1;
}
```

This means that only 1 thread is ever allowed inside the {} at the same time. If one thread is in the {}, and onther wants to go in, it neads to wait until the first is done.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I added changes. When I use Dictionary, Output is the same.

Comment: if you use a normal dictionary (not ConcurrentDictionary) and have no locks, then with this simple program, the output will be the same 99.999% of the time. But in a real life program, with more threads, and no sleeps, there will be problems.

Comment: ok I added more to the answer, if that is not enough to see what is happening, I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

> Question is, why those two threads works without Lock?

ConcurrentDictionary has its own internal lock.

> Shouldn't be that reading thread shouldn't see changes?

Why? Both threads use the same static instance of dictionary.

**Update:**

If you change `ConcurrentDictionary` to `Dictionary`, the output will remain the same. You should be pretty lucky (or rather unlucky) to hit some problem with such a simple application. However, if you use Dictionary from many different threads, especially if those threads modify dictionary, you can't be sure that you won't corrupt internal dictionary data or get some odd exceptions.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I added changes. When I use Dictionary, Output is the same.

Comment: @Update Ok, So I heard that I cant be sure but.. I always see same result. So what mechanism in .net / processor / windows / etc.. should I understand to see the bigger picture?

Comment: If you really want to see consequences of using Dictionary from different threads without locks, launch 100 or 1000 concurrent threads that add random values. May be it will work for you.